# When to say that a set is above bounded or below bounded?

Tags: analysis

for example the intervals $M = (2,6]$, $H=[1,5]$, $J=[8,\infty)$. How to specify which set is bounded and if it is bounded how to say whether it's bounded from above?

Comment: Do you know the definition of a bounded set?

Answer (score 0):

A set $M$ is bounded from above if there exists some $C$ such that for any $x \in M$, we have $x \leq C$.  For intervals on the real line, I'd start by drawing the interval and looking for a potential bound $C$.  That will lead you to understand that any interval $(a,b)$ with a finite upper bound $b$ is bounded above (by $b$).